# EC2 instance status check failed for windows server 2012

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have hosted one EC2 instance of windows server 2012 on AWS. Today while working suddenly it is showing the error:

```
Error: instance reachable failed 
And in status check 1/2 passed
```

Can anyone help how to fix or how can I recover the instance?

I have also launched a new instance and attached the volume of those instances but it's not working.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please refer [system-reachability-check](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-reachability-check/) from AWS

Comment: I have gone through this link but whenever I m attaching the disk that time it is showing system reachability failed